# Rails - Unable to visit link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to follow a tutorial by Mackenziechild.me.

Below is the code in github https://github.com/ikanyu/raddit

Demo app: https://whispering-shelf-9164.herokuapp.com/links/1

Can anyone point out why when I inspect element on the link I have created(for example Facebook link), I can clearly see facebook. However, when I click on the link, it gives me error.

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LinksController#show

Couldn't find Link with 'id'=facebook

```
def set_link
 @link = Link.find(params[:id])
end

def authorized_user
 ...
```

Thanks!!

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><a href="<%= @link.url %>"><%= @link.title %></a><br> <small>Submitted by <%= @link.user.name %></small></h1>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <%= link_to 'Visit URL', @link.url, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>

<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <%= link_to like_link_path(@link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    Upvote
    <%= @link.get_upvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to dislike_link_path(@link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
    Downvote
    <%= @link.get_downvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<% if @link.user == current_user -%>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(@link), class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', @link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3 class="comments_title">
  <%= @link.comments.count %> Comments
</h3>

<div id="comments">
  <%= render :partial => @link.comments %>
</div>
<%= simple_form_for [@link, Comment.new]  do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for this view?

Comment: done :) please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the following html to create a link in rails

```
<a href="facebook.com">Facebook.com</a>
```

Rails will link you to YourApp.com/facebook.com (which is an invalid URL).

Try re-writing your link like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook.com</a>
```

You'll need to change the code in your view to this:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1><a href="http://www.<%= @link.url %>"><%= @link.title %></a><br> <small>Submitted by <%= @link.user.name %></small></h1>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can edit your @link.url to include the string "http://www."

Comment: Hooray! I tried your way and it works! do you mind explaining why the previous doesn't work?

Comment: Basically, when you ommit the 'http://www.' Rails will simply append the href value to the end of your current url. But when you add the http:// rails will know that the value is a separate/independent url. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please accept my answer if it solved your problem... and let me know if you have any more questions :)

Comment: What if I want to include http:// at my form? It's like in the rectangle box http:// is already being included?

Currently my code is as follow:
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :url, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>